# Add Values from Rows if Column A is Blank until New Value in Column A VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a series of programs to create pre written e-mails based on the values found in the row the clicked button resides (buttons are only inserted when there is a value in column A).  What I am trying to do is also include values from Columns F and H when the cell in column A is blank until reaching the next cell in column A with a value (i.e. put the value of cells F6 and H6 as well as F7 and H7 in the e-mail string but stop because there is a value in A8)

This is my code so far:

```
     Sub SendEmail()
     Dim Outlook_App As Object
     Dim Outlook_Mail As Object
     Dim r As Range

       Set Outlook_App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
       Set Outlook_Mail = Outlook_App.CreateItem(0)
       Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
       Dim strbody As String

       strbody = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
       "Our records indicate we need to receive the following items from " & 
       Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Offset(0, 
       -11).Value & ":" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
       "Thank you,"

        On Error Resume Next
        With Outlook_Mail
       .To = Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Offset(0, 
       -4).Value
       .Subject = "ACTION NEEDED: Request for Financial Items"
       .body = strbody
       .display
       End With
       End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested the code: This might help you. Use a `IF THEN ELSE` statement with slightly different `strbody` code. The first `IF` checks if the cell below the first cell in the `r.Row` *is not empty*, and uses your current `strbody` code. The `ELSE` statement will run if the cell below the first cell in the `r.Row` *is empty*; the code `Cells(r.Row, r.Column).Offset(1, -8).Value & Cells(r.Row, r.Column).Offset(1, -6).Value` adds the values from the cell in columns F and H one row down.

```
If Cells(r.Row, r.Column).Offset(1, -13).Value <> "" Then

    strbody = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Our records indicate we need to receive the following items from " & _
    Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Offset(0, -11).Value & _
    ":" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you,"

Else
    strbody = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Our records indicate we need to receive the following items from " & _
    Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Offset(0, -11).Value & _
    Cells(r.Row, r.Column).Offset(1, -8).Value & Cells(r.Row, r.Column).Offset(1, -6).Value & _
    ":" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you,"

End If
```